# \overline outside of math mode

Tags: math-mode, environments

If I want to draw an overline over some text, not an equation, how can I do it? `\overline` seems to only work in math mode, and when used outside of math mode, it automatically says "Missing $ inserted".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Easy answer:

```
\newcommand{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\mbox{#1}}$}
```

Not so easy, but neater:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother
```

We use the normal `\overline` of math mode, exploiting the fact that a `\hbox` in math mode typesets its argument in the font which was current at the time the math formula starts (also keeping spaces).

The strange `\m@th` is a precaution against possible setting of the parameter `\mathsurround`, a space added before and after in-line math formulas; it's usually zero, but a class might change it. When math mode is used for things like this, it's best to be on the safe side: `\m@th` sets the parameter to zero, but since a math formula forms a group, the setting is local and won't change the global one.

Comment: IMHO it should be called `\textoverline`, just to be consistent with all the other `\text...` macros.

Comment: @Martin Done. The definition is just copied from the kernel (re)definition of `\underline`.

Comment: I don't know if more recent packages define it, but just to note: if `\textoverline` definition fails, using `\renewcommand` will do the trick. Really good answer!

Comment: @egreg And if `\textoverline{awordverylong}` is applied over a large word and hyphenation is necessary? Is it kept _overline_ for each one of pieces?

Comment: @skpblack You may want to look at the `soul` package.

Answer (score 14):

Use `\={o}`, it works in text mode.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you found that on TeX.SE? That would be useful to include in this answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is for getting a bar accent over *one* character, not for overlining a bunch of them.

Answer (score 12):

The basic answer to your question is that you can use the `\overline{}` command from math mode for text, too, if you combine it with `\mbox{}` command. The `\mbox{}` command lets you shift out of math mode while being in math mode. So try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\overline{\mbox{This is under a line}}$ but this isn't.
\end{document}
```

Your question was essentially answered by egreg but there wasn't much explanation and this is a little too long to put as a comment.

Comment: Or `$\bar{\text{u}}$` for single letters.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have line breaks in the text you can use the `soul` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand\ol[1]{{\setul{-0.9em}{}\ul{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\ol{This is under a line.}

\Huge\ol{This is under a line.}
\end{document}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that the line height does not depend on the height of the content (so capital letters with accents will be problematic). It does scale with font size though.

Comment: A short hint: smaller numbers in `\setul{}` (e.g. `\setul{-1.1em}`) will increase the space between line and text.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\TBox
\def\textoverline#1{\savebox\TBox{#1}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\rule[1.1\ht\TBox]{\wd\TBox}{0.4pt}}
\begin{document}

\textoverline{foo}
\textoverline{\textit{foo\"A}}
\tiny\textoverline{bar}

\end{document}
```