# Matching under- and overlines to parentheses

Tags: underline

I want to encapsulate text in a sort of inline "dialogue bubble". To do this I defined

```
% overline text 
\newcommand{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\mbox{#1}}$}
```

as seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24132/overline-outside-of-math-mode), and defined my dialogue box as

```
% dialogue box
\newcommand{\Say}[1]{%
  \textless(\underline{\textoverline{``{#1}''}})
}
```

which ends up looking like this:

[image: dialogue box attempt]

I was wondering how to match the under- and overlines to the encapsulating parentheses, and how to extend the lines a bit to overlap
more with the parentheses. I looked into using the `soul` package but
couldn't get it to work correctly :/

ADDITION: How can I have it wrap text automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are probably easier ways to do this, but here's a possibility.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\textbubble}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{\bigl(\text{$\underline{\overline{\mathstrut
    \smash{\text{#1}}}}$}\bigr)}}

\begin{document}

$\bigl(\text{$\underline{\overline{\mathstrut
  \smash{\text{``Test text''}}}}$}\bigr)$

\textbubble{Sample text}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

i've used `amsmath` and `\text` here instead of `\mbox` because `\mbox` forces the space for the argument to be both higher and deeper.  `\mathstrut` is defined to be exactly the height of a parenthesis.

this won't break across lines.