# Traditional fancy chapter headings

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I'm looking for some beautiful chapter headings for a literature book. I know about `fncychap` and `titlesec`, and I've read all the chapter headings related questions I could find on this website, but I've found them all too 'modern', whereas I am looking for something more elegant and classic. As an example of what I mean I'm attaching two images.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yet the tailpiece in your image seems not very old-style. That said, it's easy to obtain such a result with `titlesec` and a suitable font (e.g. Garamond).

Comment: Most of this is really in choice of font, and with formatting using your favourite titling package, like `titlesec` (for this kind of thing I would probably use the  `memoir` class instead, though). For the ornaments, you can use the `pgfornament` package.

Comment: If you have not already composed your document: Have a look at the `novel` document class, which is specifically intended for literature rather than math. It uses LuaLaTeX, so you can use an Open Type font without worrying about encoding. The capability to do fancy chapter headings is built in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late, but anyway :P

I used the capabilities of `titlesec` along with the Victorian Ornaments from `psvectorian` and a few other simple commands.

The `psvectorian` package is intended for using in XeLaTeX. To use it with pdfLaTeX you need the `auto-pst-pdf` package and need to compile the document with `-shell-escape` enabled (`pdflatex -shell-escape document.tex`). If you use `arara` to build your document you can just add a directive `% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }` to make things easier.

Here they are:

### The first one

A chapter name with one line above it and a double line below, and two ornaments on the sides.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[sc,compact,explicit]{titlesec} % Titlesec for configuring the header

\usepackage{tikz} % Tikz for the double underline (from: https://superuser.com/questions/1136672/double-underline-one-of-them-dashed)

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % Vectorian Ornaments XeTeX auxiliary (from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253477/how-to-use-psvectorian-with-pdflatex)
\usepackage{psvectorian} % Vectorian Ornaments

\let\clipbox\relax % PSTricks (used by PSVectorian) already defines a \clipbox, so we need this workaround
\usepackage{adjustbox} % Adjustbox to rescale the ornaments (scalebox breaks titlesec for some reason...)

\makeatletter % Defining a overline (from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24132/overline-outside-of-math-mode)
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\specdash}[1]{% % Defining a double underline (from: https://superuser.com/questions/1136672/double-underline-one-of-them-dashed)
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw ([yshift=-5pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-5pt]todotted.south east); % 5 pt below
        \draw ([yshift=-7pt]todotted.south west) -- ([yshift=-7pt]todotted.south east); % and 7 pt below
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\fancydraw}{% Defining a command to shorten things
\begin{adjustbox}{max height=0.5\baselineskip}% Rescaling to have height of 0.5\baselineskip
  \rotatebox{90}{% And rotating 90 degrees
    \psvectorian{26}% Ornament n° 26 (http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/psvectorian.pdf)
  }%
\end{adjustbox}%
}

\titleformat% Formatting the header
  {\chapter} % command
  [block] % shape - Only managed to get it working with block
  {\normalfont\bfseries\sc\huge} % format - Change here as needed
  {} % label - Not using labels
  {0pt} % sep
  {\centering % Centering the title
    \textoverline{% Overlined
    \specdash{% And double-underlined
    \fancydraw% Inserting the ornament
    \hspace{1em}% Adding a space to the text
    #1% The actual chapter name
    \hspace{1em}% Another space after the title
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\fancydraw}% and a 180 degree rotated version of the ornament
}}}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{The beginning}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

#### The Result

[image: Result of the first form of the header]

### The second one

A "Chapter N°", an ornament with one rule on each side, and the chapter name below.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[sc,compact,explicit]{titlesec} % Titlesec for configuring the header

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % Vectorian Ornaments XeTeX auxiliary (from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253477/how-to-use-psvectorian-with-pdflatex)
\usepackage{psvectorian} % Vectorian Ornaments

\let\clipbox\relax % PSTricks (used by PSVectorian) already defines a \clipbox, so we need this workaround
\usepackage{adjustbox} % Adjustbox to rescale the ornaments (scalebox breaks titlesec for some reason...)

\newcommand{\otherfancydraw}{% Defining a command to shorten things
\begin{adjustbox}{max height=0.5\baselineskip}% Rescaling to have height of 0.5\baselineskip
  \raisebox{-0.25\baselineskip}{
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{% And rotating 90 degrees
    \psvectorian{7}% Ornament n° 26 (http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/psvectorian.pdf)
  }}%
\end{adjustbox}%
}

% A command to create a rule centered vertically on the text (from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15119/draw-horizontal-line-left-and-right-of-some-text-a-single-line/15122#15122)
\newcommand*\ruleline[1]{\par\noindent\raisebox{.8ex}{\makebox[\linewidth]{\hrulefill\hspace{1ex}\raisebox{-.8ex}{#1}\hspace{1ex}\hrulefill}}}

\titleformat% Formatting the header
  {\chapter} % command
  [block] % shape - Only managed to get it working with block
  {\normalfont\bfseries\sc\huge} % format - Change here as needed
  {\centering Chapter \thechapter\\} % The Chapter N° label
  {0pt} % sep
  {\centering \ruleline{\otherfancydraw}\\ % The horizontal rule
  \centering #1} % And the actual title

\begin{document}
\chapter{The beginning}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

#### The Result

[image: Result of the second form of the header]